# how do I refresh the entire contents of recycler view to default values including the icons they're on except the current position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-image, android-viewholder, android-background

I have an app where on click of an item I am updating the background image in viewholder in adapter. However, i want to do it such that when I click on one item all other items revert to default images( sort of like toggle back ). Say I have a play button on item 1 and I click it, it switches to pause, then I click on item 2 and it switches to pause and the first button in item 1 switches back to play button. Is there a way to do that in recycler view?

Here's my code in onclick:

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                        if(!tracks.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMediaUrl().equals(currenturl) ){
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            mediaPlayer.release();

                            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


                            currenturl = tracks.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMediaUrl();
                            currentposition = getAdapterPosition();
                            playAudio(tracks.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMediaUrl());


                        }
```

I want to update the currently clicked image such that

```
mediaUrl.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
```

for the current item, but reverts back to

```
mediaUrl.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
```

for the previous item clicked , or can be refreshed to the default value for all other items in the recycleview. Any idea how to go about this in the easiest way posssible? Thanks!

Comment: you need to add a listener and send it to activity/fragment, and update the result to all items in your list by calling notifyDataSetChanged(). if it is just one item to update, then remember and update item in list then call notifyItemChanged(index)

Comment: any examples of how to go about that?

Comment: Search for single checked item in recycler view, same concept but You'll replace images instead of changing checkbox state.

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

create variable inside your recyclerview adapter itemselected = "number of currently selected item".
in your viewHolder bind check the itemSelectedIndex and apply the style appropriately.

Make onClickListener for the event where you waht to select some item. In the onClick set the itemSelectedIndex = "item number which was clicked". And then call (also in the same method) notifyDataSetChahged.

This will do the job. 
notifyDataSetChanged will make your recyclerview to redraw whole item. And, since the "selected" view will also be applied to the itemSelectedIndex item, others will turn unselected.

In order to improve performance of this solution you might want to introduce two indexes:
itemSelected
itemSelectedPrevious.
In this case, in onClick do:

```
itemSelectedPrevious = itemSelected
itemSelected = "index of current clicked item"
notifyItemChanged(itemSelectedPrevious)
notifyItemChanged(itemSelected)
```

in this case you'll avoid redrawing of the whole recycleradapter view, but will only update previously selected item to change it's state to non-selected, and also the current item to be active.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am sort of confused by what you mentioned. I tried it out based on my understanding and didnt work. Can you explain with respect to my code if possible?